# the connected state of the office add-ins registered in hkey_local_machine cannot be changed WIX

Tags: outlook, wix

am using a wix installer to create an MSI package. While i try to install my outlook addin to everyone (allusers), it gets installed properly in the administrator, but it is not visible in other user group logins, 
while i tried to manually enable the addin from the Options-> Addins, i get the below error
"the connected state of the office add-ins registered in hkey_local_machine cannot be changed".
i am using adxloader.
Is there something am missing in the installer ? my code for all users are below
"

> Property Id="ALLUSERS" Value="1"
>
> RegistryKey Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\xxxxx.AddinModule">
>
> > Condition>USER_PROFILE="ALLUSERS" /Condition>
> >     "

Answer (score 0):

What is the version of the targeted office?

Add In registration for Office 2007 is different to Office 2010 and 2013.

For Office 2007, check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb206739%28v=office.12%29.aspx